# Can univariate analysis find the p value, HZ ratio from the 100% alive group analysis

Tags: p-value, separation

I try to compare two groups in univariate analysis but there are some problems because one group was alive only (no dead)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ performs fine in this situation.  The point estimate of $\infty$ is also OK.  Ignore the standard error.  To get confidence limits use the profile likelihood method.